# Сравнение вещественных чисел

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста не понимаю в чем ошибка. Нужно сделать функцию, которая вставляет в массив действительных чисел, отсортированный в порядке возрастания значений элементов, дополнительное число, сохраняя общую упорядоченность.

```
long double sortArr[10] = { 123.12,234.45,1463.34,12452.1,14656.35,21443.123,65409.67,78558.32,87686.21 };

long double  sortWithadditionalNumb(long double arr[], int *quantity) {
int i;
long double additionalNumber;
printf("\nВедите еще одно вещественное число ");
scanf_s("%Lf", &additionalNumber);
getchar();
for (i = *quantity; i>0; i--) {
    if (arr[i] > additionalNumber) {
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }
    if (arr[i] < additionalNumber) {
        arr[i - 1] = additionalNumber;
        break;
    }

}
/*
for (i = *quantity; i>0; i--) {
    if (*(arr + i) > additionalNumber) {
        *(arr + i + 1) = *(arr + i);
    }
    if (*(arr + i) < additionalNumber) {
        *(arr + i - 1) = additionalNumber;
        break;
    }

}
*/
(*quantity)++;
for (int x = 0; x<*quantity; x++) {
    printf("%.8Lg ", *(arr + x));
}
return additionalNumber;
```

}

Comment: а почему вы берете  указатель для задания размера массива?  Не в том ошибка, но все же...

Comment: Да для задания размера чтоб потом  его увеличить.Мне сказали так лучше.

Comment: *quantity, это есть обьект,  адрес которого содержит указатель  quantity.  Логичнее сразу использовать сам обьект, чем потом везде разыменовывать указатель...

Comment: понял вас, но  если потом мне потребуется количество чтобы дальше с ним работать в других функциях лучше оставить указатель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикле:

```
if (arr[i] < additionalNumber) {
    arr[i - 1] = additionalNumber;
    break;
}
```

нужно вставлять в `arr[i + 1]`, так как элементы у вас все время смещались вправо.

Comment: Действительно вы правы исправил, но при первой проверке этого самого цикла он возвращает True даже когда число является меньше элемента в массиве.

Comment: Непонял: что возвращает? Вы может меня неправильно поняли: там где у вас - нужен +

Comment: я исправил эту ошибку но когда когда программа доходит   `if (arr[i] < additionalNumber) ` условие всегда происходит даже  когда additionalNumber=0

Comment: Наверное ошибка ввода. Попробуйте перед условием вывести. Чему равеяются arr[i] и additionalNumber

Comment: все хорошо только что проверил. arr[i]=123.120000  additionalNumber== 32.234000

Comment: когда вывожу массив получается {123.12 , 234.45 , 1163.34 , 1252.1  ,1656.35 , 2443.123 , 5409.67 , 8558.32 , 8766.21 , 0  ,32.234 ,0} (изменил числа)

Comment: А почему 123.12 - это вроде 1-й элемент массива, а вы итерируете с конца

Comment: разобрался в чем ошибка я плохо поставил quantity и оно всегда сравнивали с 0.
Спасибо очень выручили. На будущее буду внимательнее.